# TRANSACTION - Como corrigir um erro de transporte?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, transações, rollback

Acho que dá para entender o que eu estou querendo fazer aí:
Esse método vai fazer um `foreach` para cada item da minha lista de movimentações, e enviar cada uma delas como parâmetro para o método que irá salva-las no BD.

Eu preciso usar uma Transaction para garantir que, ou todas essas movimentações sejam enviadas, ou nenhuma, para garantir a consistência das informações.

Forcei a execução daquele método sem a internet, para entrar no catch, e encontrei um problema na linha `transaction.Rollback();`:

> Additional information: Um erro no nível de transporte ocorreu ao
>   enviar a solicitação ao servidor. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 -
>   Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto.)

Agradeço muito a alma caridosa que tiver tempo e boa vontade de ajudar a esse iniciante :)

O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
public static void SalvaNotaFiscalXML(IList<MovimentacaoDTO> movimentacoesNotaFiscal)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CS1))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cnx.Open();
                    SqlTransaction transaction;
                    transaction = cnx.BeginTransaction("MovimentacaoDeEstoque");
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = cnx;
                        cmd.Transaction = transaction;


                        foreach (var item in movimentacoesNotaFiscal)
                        {
                            MovimentacaoBLL.NewMovimentacao(item);
                        }

                        transaction.Commit();
                        cnx.Close();
                        return;
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex2)
                    {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            cnx.Close();
                            throw ex2;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: Erro de transporte é relativo a erro na camada TCP. Dentro do modelo TCP/IP, a camada de transporte fica entre a camada de rede e a camada de aplicação. Se deu erro no TCP, então isso implica em normalmente que alguma coisa além do alcance normal da programação está interferindo, como rede oscilante ou corrupção dos dados de modo que o TCP aborte a conexão por ela não ter salvação

Answer (score 1):

O **Rollback** ocorrerá automaticamente se a conexão com o banco de dados cair. Ou seja, antes de executar o rollback verifique se a **conexão está aberta**, fazendo isso, se a **rede cair**, o Rollback ocorrerá automaticamente, mas se ocorrer **outro tipo de erro**, como um dado inválido, será necessário executar o rollback.

```
          catch (SqlException ex2)
                {
                        if (cnx.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                           transaction.Rollback();
                           cnx.Close();
                        }
                        throw ex2;
                }
```